# Install old work low voltage bracket in too big hole

Tags: low-voltage, brackets, old-work

I'm trying to repair a low voltage outlet that was butchered by our cable installer. I was hoping I could reuse the bracket he had used by the "wings" were on serrated or corrugated tabs that could not be moved back. So I bought a Carlon SC100RR Old Work Outlet Box, 1-Gang, Non-Metallic bracket. The first problem I encountered is those screws are murder to turn. The bigger problem is the opening is a titch bigger than the bracket on all four sides. Plus the drywall at the top was destroyed by the installer so I had to mount a thin piece of wood behind the top just to have something the wing to grab. Unfortunately, the hole is still bigger than the bracket. When I try to tighten the wings, the bracket falls into the hole. The faceplate has four openings for coax and speaker terminals.
[image]
What are my options?

Comment: Is it alongside a stud, or anything meaty you could attach a box to, *the old fashioned way*?  Hanging boxes off "only the drywall" using those gimpy little wing-clamps is not a best practice, it's a cheap shortcut.  Also, you're not *required* to use open-back brackets... you are free to use actual junction boxes.  Including metal boxes if you see fit. Metal boxes are great for improvising attachments to stud mounting.  The cables can come in knockout holes.

Comment: A picture of the box in the hole in the drywall, showing how much room there is still to fill might get you some better ideas. A generic pic off the internet of a random face plate doesn't do much to describe your situation.

Comment: If I was installing coax and wanted it to stay attached to the wall for longer than the first time some gorilla tried attaching a cable to it, I would in this instance cut the wall back to a stud, firmly install a metal box on the stud, then patch up the wall around it.  Those low voltage old work boxes always get ripped off the wall when used with coax.  YOu may as well NOT use a box, just patch it up with a 1/2 inch hole and leave the coax cables dangling out terminated and ready to use.

Comment: But seriously, installing new coax?  Where are you going to put the [telex](https://youtu.be/S81GyMKH7zw?t=244) machine?

Comment: jay613 - Where I live it's either spectrum coax or satellite.

Answer (score 2):

1. Repair the drywall, cut a new opening. Possibly move the opening while you are at it.
2. Change to a double-gang ring. Have some blank spots in your faceplate, no big deal.
3. Depending on the details of the damaged hole, use an actual box, rather than an LV ring

Comment: Actually, if you go to a double-gang and make it two in each side instead of 4 in a single-gang, nobody would know it wasn't simply planned that way and it would look fine.

Comment: Yes, 4-holes are available in double-gang. I'm used to stocking higher numbers of holes and blank inserts for the unused (or future expansion) ones.

Comment: When in the business it makes sense to minimize SKUs and allow for expansion (I do that too, though I do less cabling than I used to). But for a one-off DIY, getting it "just right" makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Extra low voltage is basically unregulated, almost anything goes:

Glue and/or screw some thin plywood to the back of the drywall, repair the gaps in the drywall then screw the outlet and surround through the repaired drywall to the plywood.